# Updating file on GoogleDrive (App Folder)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, realm, drive

I am uploading backup of my realm database onto Google Drive inside appfolder but the issue is whenever I upload backup it make the new backup file and increase the storage of drive .
I have tried updating it with

`mDriveService.files().update(existingToken,metadata, inputStreamContent);`

but this gives me the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 
Forbidden

{
“code”: 403,
“errors”: [
{
  “domain”: “global”,
  “message”: “The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead.“,
  “reason”: “fieldNotWritable”
}
],
“message”: “The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead.”
}
```

when I tried deleting it then it gives me following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden


{
“code”: 403,
“errors”: [
{
  “domain”: “global”,
  “message”: “The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.“,
  “reason”: “fieldNotWritable”
}
 ],
 “message”: “The resource body includes fields which are not directly 
writable.”
}
```

I just want to update the file or replace the existing file with new file.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the request you are doing to check if it is correctly written. Do you have permissions for the parent folders of the one you are trying to update?

Comment: @Kessy I don't know about how to give permissions to parent . please let me know.

Comment: If it's your drive, you should have all the permissions, so it would be a code related issue. If it's a shared drive you should ask the owner of the drive to grant you permissions.

Comment: @Kessy I couldn't find any way to give permissions could you please help me?

Comment: Are you the owner of the folder?

Also you can read this 2 docs:

Give permission through code: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Give permission through Drive: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: @Kessy I have given permissions to it but it still not working, like when I upload it first time it works smoothly but when I try to update it , it gives me following error: Fail  Method not supported for files within the Application Data folder.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this issue, solved using following `code`:

```
 uploadedFile = mDriveService.files().update(fileId, null, mediaContent).execute();
```

Where `fileId` is google drive id of file to be updated.

Please note to pass 2nd arg as `null`, the actual content would be passed in 3rd arg.

Answer (score 0):

```
mService.files().update(fileId, metadata, generateFileContents())
                .setFields("id, name, appProperties")
                .execute();
```

**fileId** is the id of the file you want to update.